# Expanded navigation by default

Tags: module, javascript, navigation, design

I use the Sidebar Navigation Menu Professional for Magento by CODNITIVE and I am trying to make it expanded by default. Particularly I need a solution to make just the first list item expanded by default. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[

Codnitive = {

    expandMenu: function(parent) 
    {
        var mode = parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getAttribute("expanded");
        (mode == 1) ? Codnitive.collapse(parent) : Codnitive.expand(parent);
    },

    expand: function(parent)
    {
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.backgroundPosition = "right center";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("expanded", "1");
    },

    collapse: function(parent)
    {
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.backgroundPosition = "left center";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("expanded", "0");
    }

};



//]]>
</script>
```

In another forum there was the suggestion to use:

```
Codnitive.expand(document.getElementById('the-menu-parent-element-id'));
```

Where exactly should I write this code to make it work? Sorry, but I am not familiar with js.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should add this condition in line 280:

```
        if ($category->getId() == '35') {
            $expanded = 1;
        }
```

In this way the category with ID 35 will be expanded by default. There is still another little problem - the "plus" sign remains but it should be "minus" for collapsing the category.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather edit CODNITIVE's Navigation.php in app/code/community/codnitive/sidenav/block/

on about line 289 there should be

```
if ($height == 0) {
    $extraStyle = ' display:none;';
}
```

if you remove display:none it should be visible.
You can also add a condition using the $level variable.

Just have a look at the code it's quite straightforward in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the file to edit but it doesn't work with display:none. I should edit `code` if ($config->isCollapsible()) {
            $width = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() === 'arrow' ? 8 : 16;
            $height = 0;
            $expanded = 1 (instead of 0);`code`
But the problem is only partially solved - the "plus" image is still a plus like the menu is still collapsable. 
I tried to add this condition, but without success - `code`if($category->getId()==35): {
            $expanded = 1;
   }`code`